# Effect of unwinding recursion on different types of variables

Tags: java, recursion

I noted today that in Java, arrays and primitives behave differently when they are part of a recursive function. For example, consider the following recursive code for finding the number of ways an integer (N) can be expressed in coins of different denominations given by an array (denom[]):

```
public static void printAll(int ind, int[] denom,int N,int[] vals){
    if(N==0){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
        return;
    }
    if(ind == (denom.length))return;             
    int currdenom = denom[ind];
    for(int i=0;i<=(N/currdenom);i++){
        vals[ind] = i;
        printAll(ind+1,denom,N-i*currdenom,vals);
    }
 }
```

It is obvious that when the function calls itself, it carries the variables vars (that is storing the actual numbers for each denomination) and N with it into the next call and so, they remain the same. However, when the recursion unwinds (one function call is done and the program goes back to the last one) it gets interesting. Now, the value of N immediately resets to what it was when the call that just got unwound was made. This is fortunate because this function relies on that behavior. However, the vals[] array behaves differently than that. It preserves all changes made to it from the unwound call. This doesn't pose problems here as it is updated the next time it goes into the loop. However, I was curious why primitives and arrays behave differently in Java. Also, can this behavior be expected in C, C++ and C# as well? Note that if N was a part of some array instead of a stand alone primitive argument, this function wouldn't work.

Comment: This happens because primitives are passed by value while arrays and objects are passed by reference values. It happens for all functions and is unrelated to recursion.

Comment: Not just arrays, but all Objects (all non-primitives), are passed as arguments to the target method by reference, and thus will demonstrate the same behavior you see here for arrays.

Comment: Is it possible to change that behavior? Also, is it the same for the other languages?

Comment: No, this is how it always works in Java. In C# you have the `ref` keyword that allows passing primitives by reference, C has pointers, and C++ has pointers and reference types.

Comment: What do you want to change it to, and why?

Comment: I want that if N were lets say, the last element of the denom array, the function should still work. It won't currently as the changes from the unwound call will be preserved.

Comment: There are no changes to the N variables as a copy is made for every stack frame. If you know how the call stack works this should probably be clear?

Comment: Other terms for what @ZongZhengLi says: the difference is between "boxed" types, which are accessed through named references (`Array` and all descendants of `Object`) and "unboxed" ones (like `int`, `float`, and `char`) where the name stands for the object itself.  The _references_ to the boxed types behave just like the integer N in your example.  Unboxed types and references are both copied during recursive descent.  But the objects the references _point to_ - those with boxed type - are not copied.  So their values persist through both descent and unwinding.

Comment: Thanks guys, this clears it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the Java's parameter passing mechanism. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)